Error TS2307: Cannot find module while deploying
I cloned repo and then did a deployment onto Cloudflare worker for staging server. Server will not run live until this issue is resolved. I ran the command npm run frontend: build and it outputs the following error:

Seems like it is unable to import data from Zod validation module. Has anyone experienced a problem like this as I am not able to troubleshoot and figure this out.

The shipaxxess-zod-v4 package can not search in npm.
But I found another way, it's in github
Official Link: https://github.com/pwz2k/shipaxxess-v4/tree/master/shipaxxess-zod-v4
you can use following case to solve your problem:
// package.json
{
    "dependencies": {
        "@shipaxxess": "git+https://github.com/pwz2k/shipaxxess-v4.git"
    },
    
}


it's useful


Ok the problem is the code works locally, but deploying on Cloudflare workers it does not.
https://i.imgur.com/KGPgXze.png
